# AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute '_fields' - Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I'm just adding some related fields to my model, some other fields work, but for this model they just won't, these are my models:

```
class book_block(models.Model):
    _name = 'book.block'

    name = fields.Char(string="Name")
    code = fields.Char(string="Code", size=11)
    size_code = fields.Many2one('bsi.book.block.size', string="Size")
    text_paper = fields.Many2one('text.paper', string="Text Paper")
    n_pages_one_color = fields.Integer(string="N° of pages 1 color")
    adnl_n_pages_one_color = fields.Integer(string="Additional N° of pages one color")

class mrp_worksheet_contract(models.Model):
    _name = 'mrp.worksheet.contract'

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        if vals.get('name', 'New') == 'New':
            vals['name'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('mrp.worksheet.contract') or '/'
        return super(mrp_worksheet_contract, self).create(vals)

    name = fields.Char('Reference', required=True, index=True, copy=False, readonly='True', default='New')
    date = fields.Date(string="Date")
    book_block = fields.Many2one('book.block', string="Book Block")
    n_pages_one_color = fields.Integer(string="N of pages one color", related="book_block.n_pages_one_color")
    adnl_n_pages_one_color = fields.Integer(string="Additional N° of pages one color", related="book_block.adnl_n_pages_one_color")
```

The `book_block` field is okay, the issue comes with `n_pages_one_color` and `adnl_n_pages_one_color` fields, it throws me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 546, in _handle_exception
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 583, in dispatch
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 319, in _call_function
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\service\model.py", line 118, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 316, in checked_call
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 812, in __call__
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 412, in response_wrap
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 948, in call_button
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\base\module\module.py", line 447, in button_immediate_install
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\base\module\module.py", line 495, in _button_immediate_function
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\modules\registry.py", line 370, in new
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 355, in load_modules
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 255, in load_marked_modules
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 156, in load_module_graph
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\modules\registry.py", line 194, in setup_models
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 372, in old_api
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 3010, in _setup_fields
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\fields.py", line 468, in setup
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\fields.py", line 514, in _setup_related
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute '_fields'
```

I don't get it, it should work, I don't see anything wrong on it, even `book_block Many2one` field is Okay, so, what's the deal?

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your model in the same module (odoo addon)  and when you remove the related field m2o fields works perfectly!!!

Comment: Yes it's on the same addon, even same .py file, and yes, when I remove them it works as it should, it loads the Many2one, but not the related fields to that Many2one, is very strange to me...

Comment: ''do you have this error when you install the module or upgrade it.

Comment: Both cases, actually :/

Comment: Try to remove one field and don't use them in the view and see if evey thing goes fine check your code again you may did some mistake that you can miss

Comment: Gonna try :) ...

Comment: There is something weird, did that, still same error, but what is more puzzling, is that this very same book.block model and relationship works well on other models, changed the fields, changed some other things, same error, there must be something on that worksheet class

Comment: Can you put the full py file from import to last line

Comment: It was an _inherit on another class, on another class I was inheriting 'mrp.contract.wokrhseet' and that was the problem, just commented the _inherit and that was it, weird...

Comment: my suggetion to find out what is the problem: clean your environment (clean cache, delete unused database) and try to install in new fresh database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not refering to Boolean (not bool) fields. The error is generated (from the tracebak: **File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server.\openerp\fields.py", line 514, in _setup_related**) from **_setup_related** method, which, according to the source code: Setup the attributes of a related field. So, I would suggest that you check any fields that has related attribute.
And check if **adnl_n_pages_one_color** field exist in **book_block** model.

Answer (score 1):

May be you need to import '_' from openerp.. Like this:

```
from openerp.tools.translate import _
```